# anguar.js - event listening via $on returns undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new to angular and was testing around a little bit with a product filter for exercising. I want the product controller to listen to some event. However, I get this error once the site is loaded:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

on the line of $scope.$on. I'm pretty sure the $on is the problem.

This may be a really stupid question, but I just cant seem to find any hints on this.

Thanks a lot

```
var testApp = angular.module('marketPlace', []);

testApp.controller('ProductsController', [ '$http', function($scope, $http){
    var products = this;
    products.errorNotice = "";
    products.currentlyShowingDetails = false;
    products.minActualPrice = 0;
    products.maxActualPrice = 0;
    products.regions = 0;
    products.suppliers = 0;
    products.commodities = 0;
    products.properties = 0;


    $scope.$on('filterChange', function(event, args) {
        console.log(args);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not injecting `$scope` correctly.

`testApp.controller('ProductsController', [ '$http', function($scope, $http){`
 is the problem. You're injecting `$http` as `$scope`. Try to change it to

`testApp.controller('ProductsController', [ '$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){`

Or even better

```
@ngInject
testApp.controller('ProductsController', function($scope, $http){
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-inject